# (`library`.`book_loans`, CONSTRAINT `book_loans_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`isbn`) REFERENCES `book` (`isbn`))

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`library`.`book_loans`, CONSTRAINT `book_loans_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`isbn`) REFERENCES `book` (`isbn`))

Here is my code for tables

| **book_loans** |

```
CREATE TABLE `book_loans` (
    `loan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `isbn` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Card_ID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date_out` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `due_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_in` date DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`loan_id`),
    KEY `book_loans_ibfk_2` (`Card_ID`),
    KEY `isbn` (`isbn`),
    CONSTRAINT `book_loans_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Card_ID`) 
        REFERENCES `borrower` (`Card_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `book_loans_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`isbn`) 
        REFERENCES `book` (`isbn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1002 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
    COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

| **book**  |

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
    `isbn` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`isbn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
    COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

| **borrower** |

```
CREATE TABLE `borrower` (
    `Card_ID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Ssn` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Bname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Card_ID`),
    UNIQUE KEY `Ssn` (`Ssn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1002 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
    COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: That is not valid T-SQL, I assume you aren't using SQL Server so why have you tagged it? SQL Server and MySQL are 2 very different RDBMS. In regards to your code, please do take the time to format it; it's not readable as it is. Finally, it seems you forgot to ask a question, which is really important when posting a **question**. Please do ask us a question so we can help you. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely your `PRIMARY KEY` meaning the `loan_id`  column should be the `AUTO_INCREMENT` one in the `book_loans` table, that should fix your error.

Comment: I formated your code and removed the SQL-Server tag, since this is obviously MySQL code. Now can you please edit your question to tell us what  you were doing when you received this error, and what in the error message is unclear to you.

Answer (score -1):

This exception may occur when you have inserted a value for the "isbn" attribute of the "book_loans" table that is not included in the set of primary key values.